# Windows 10: How to open the entire window when clicking on a taskbar button?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, taskbar

Say I have 10 tabs open in Firefox. Windows' taskbar currently groups the 10 tabs into one button on my taskbar. Currently, if I am in another application, when I click on the Firefox button in the taskbar, all the Firefox tabs display in a preview mode, I must pick one of the tabs in order to land back into my Firefox. See picture below.

[image: Screen shot]

What I would like is:

1) Keep the feature that different tabs are grouped into one button
2) When I click on the Firefox button, the entire Firefox window opens.I do not need to click twice in order to get back to Firefox.

How do I make this change?

Comment: Are you hovering on the taskbar icon, or just clicking it? If you hover, you'll get the tab previews.

Comment: I click on the taskbar icon, but I have to click another time (pick one of the tabs) in order to get back to Firefox.

Comment: I also realized this may be a Firefox setting issue but I am having trouble pinpointing what it is. The current issue is Windows 10 treats all of my Firefox TABS as windows, that is why I have to click twice to get back to Firefox. These are actually tabs, not windows. I want them to be treated as such. Any ideas?

Comment: Is that what you are looking for ? https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/1051658

Answer (score 1):

`about:preferences#general` in your Firefox settings (Tools → Options → General)

You need to uncheck `Show tab previews in the Windows taskbar`
[image: Firefox screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

No setting in Windows 10 can configure button click operation.

What I can think of is using tab + Alt keys combination to switch window.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, go to `Tools -> Options -> General`, uncheck the box for `Show tab previews in the Windows taskbar`.